# What's the more conservative way of saving images from PDF files?

Tags: adobe-acrobat, save

I'm going to use a PDF example for my question. I'll also use a large image, so I can express my doubts better (so, I'm already sorry for the image size).

[image]

Above you can see the image as it should be. I've obtained it clicking with the "Take a Snapshot" tool whithin Adobe Acrobat Pro DC. Here's another page example:

[image]

Now, whenever I try to export these PDF pages as images (using the built-in `file -> export -> as image`), I get these results (I've exported them in PNG):

[image]

[image]

As you can see, two effect are observed:

- The vector images (made in Adobe Illustrator) got distorted and messy;
- There is a significant loss of quality, both for the unmatched vector and the texts (it got all crackled up and pixelated).

My main goal (it should be clear now from the images) is using these as slides for my drawing tablet. The thing is, I cannot believe that there is no built-in function on Adobe Acrobat (or some other application some of you may suggest) that would do the same I've done with the "Snapshot" tool. With it (and afterwards opening Photoshop and saving the image as PNG) I get satisfactory results. Otherwise I can't (and I don't want to use the "Snapshot" feature, since it can't massively do it with all the pages at once, I'd have to mechanically do it page by page; that, I don't want to).

So, could you help me with this specific step?

Comment: erm.... huh? I don't understand what you are trying to ask. If you just want to create PNGs of the pages, open the PDF pages with Photoshop and export them.

Comment: I didn't know you could do that. Do you suggest exporting the pages using the "image processor" within "scripts", in PS?

Comment: So, apparently using the Image Processor doesn't work. When I try it, I get the following error message: "There were no source files that could be opened by Photoshop". I really wanted something to avoid individually treating the pages (I'll be dealing with LOTS of them), but the action shortcut tip is a good one. Thanks again!

Comment: What's your OS? On a Mac you could do that in 5 seconds with Automator

Answer (score 2):

You can simply open a PDF with Photoshop and it will allow you to select what pages to open, then open the pages as individual images (rasterized).

Once you have them open in Photoshop, you can use any number of methods to save or export them as PNG files. You could even configure an action with a custom shortcut, to save then close the image. So at worse case you'd merely need to tap that shortcut repeatedly.

I'm not familiar with AcrobatDC (prefer Acrobat X here), but in previous versions of Acrobat you can also merely save pages as PNGs from within Acrobat. Simply choose `File > Save As > Image > PNG` from the menu. Again, I can't say for certain that option still exists in AcrobatDC, but it's rare that Adobe *removes* a feature.